# Polyline points not showing in my flutter map project

Tags: flutter, api, dictionary

I'm trying to implement a map that shows direction and realtime location. I have gotten my API for the flutter project and specified it in all applications i need -iOS, android and web.
Then i imported the necessary packages needed for implemneting it. The map is showing but the polyline points isn't it keeps giving me this error.

*Error: XMLHttpRequest error.*

This is the stateful widget of the map.

```
class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
  Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // getCurrentLocation();
     getPolyPoints();
    super.initState();
  }

  static const LatLng sourceLocation =
  LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962);

  static const LatLng destination =
      LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792);

  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return   GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: sourceLocation,
        zoom: 14.4746,
      ),
      markers: {

        Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('source'),
            position: sourceLocation
        ),
        Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('destination'),
            position: destination
        ),
      },
      polylines: {
        Polyline(
          polylineId: const PolylineId('route'),
          points: polylineCoordinates,
          color: signUpPageBackgroundColor,

        )
      },
    );
  }

  void getPolyPoints() async {
    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints
        .getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      googleApiKey,
      PointLatLng(sourceLocation.latitude, sourceLocation.longitude),
      PointLatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude),
    );

    if(result.points.isNotEmpty){
      result.points
          .forEach((PointLatLng point)
      => polylineCoordinates.add(
          LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
      );
      setState(() {});
    }else{
      print(result.errorMessage);
    }
    print(result.points);
  }
}
```

I tried restricting the google_api, thinking that was the problem but it still didn't work. Initially the map wasn't showing because I was using a device preview package, but I downloaded google_map_web and it worked, but the polyline_points has support for web version of map, but it isn't showing.